# Uniqueness of duality data

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am referring to Dan Freed's Q3 of [homework 2](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/homework2.pdf).  It says the following:

let $y \in C$ be a dualizable object in a symmetric monoidal category and suppose $(y^{\vee},c,e)$ and $(\widetilde{y{\vee}},\tilde{c},\tilde{e})$ are two sets of duality data, then there exists a unique map $(y^{\vee},c,e) \to (\widetilde{y^{\vee}},\tilde{c},\tilde{e})$.

Could somebody give a hint as to where I can get some sort of "uniqueness" and pass it down to this map?

Comment: First try to write down any map. The units and counits will be useful.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: sorry what is a unit and counit?  Freed does not define them in the lecture.  And why?  There is a uniqueness associated with unit/counit?